# AND operator between tables when both have multiple records (multiple row to multiple row check)

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I have three tables `[AvailableEmployees]`, `[AvailableAttributesTemp]` and `[EmployeeAttributeMapping]`.

[AvailableEmployees]

```
Id       Name
1000     Employee 1
1001     Employee 2
1002     Employee 3
1003     Employee 4
1004     Employee 5
```

[AvailableAttributesTemp] temp table could have more rows

```
Id  AttributeName
1   HRA
3   DA
```

[EmployeeAttributeMapper]

```
EmployeeId  AttributeId    
1000        1
1000        3
1001        1
1002        1
1002        3
1003        1
1004        4
```

I want to get only `EmployeeId`'s who have all the attributes from `[AvailableAttributesTemp]` (`HRA` and `DA` both, although there could be more than two attributes listed), So any query to get 1000, 1002.

I wrote a query using IN operator which returns 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003. Now trying to update the query to use AND operator to filter out the employee, Tried EXISTS, JOIN though somehow not able to get the desired result.

This scenario is a part of large SP with multiple temp tables and more than 500 query line/s.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for more than just the two attributes. Let's say `AvailableAttributesTemp]` contaIns 10 attributes: Do you want the employees with all 10 attributes then? Or the employees with a given list which can range from 1 to 10 attributes (e.g. attributes 'HRA' and 'DA')?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Nick tagged SQL Server for you. Is this correct? (I suppose Nick guessed SQL Server from your using brackets around table names, but this could just as well be SQLite or MS Access).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes MS SQL server, Sorry forgot to use SqlServer as tag instead used Sql.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I also looked at OPs previous questions to figure out what it was likely to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just select all employee ids from `EmployeeAttributeMapper` where the count of `AttributeId` for that employee is the same as the count of all rows from `AvailableAttributesTemp`:

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM EmployeeAttributeMapper
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AttributeId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AvailableAttributesTemp)
```

Output:

```
EmployeeID
1000
1002
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/20423/2)

Note I've included a `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` of `AttributeID` in case there may be duplicate records in `EmployeeAttributeMapper`. If that can't be the case, you can remove `DISTINCT` from that part of the query.

Comment: How silly of me not to figure that out :) . Thanks for help.

Comment: Agree :), Will add one or more AttributeId check to make sure both of them tables have same attribute type (HRA and DA instead of any other but thats obviously was not part of question) but this is a good start. Going to try this approach later today.